# "If you could sign up for my website, it would be great."

Tags: conditional-constructions

I have some vague queries about 2nd conditional sentence structure.

> 1. If you could sign up for my website, it would be great.

Is this a sort of 2nd conditional sentence that assumes an unlikely situation?

> 2. If you enjoyed my video, please subscribe to my channel.

I know that a 2nd conditional structure is "if + past tense verb, ~" and it supposes a situation that is unlikely to happen. But, it seems that this example doesn't suppose an unlikely situation although it has a 2nd conditional structure. It's very confusing for me.

Answer (score 2):

Think of your second example like this:

> ***If it is true*** that you enjoyed my video, please subscribe to my channel.

or

> ***If this is the case*** (that you enjoyed my video), please subscribe to my channel.

So it could be considered [a first conditional with imperative](http://www.focus.olsztyn.pl/en-grammar-conditionals-I.html#:%7E:text=In%20this%20type%20of%20conditional,is%20assumed%20by%20the%20speaker.).